# how can i disable inputs if an array is full and not allow inputs if all fields are not filled in?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

```
$(document).ready(readyNow);

let garage = [];

function readyNow() {
  console.log('JQ');
  $('#addCarButton').on('click', addCar)
} //end readyNow

function addCar() {
  console.log('in addCar');
  //get unser inputs
  //create new object
  let newCar = {
    year: $('#yearInput').val(),
    make: $('#makeInput').val(),
    model: $('#modelInput').val()
  }
  //push the new car into the array
  garage.push(newCar);
  //empty inputs
  $('#yearInput').val('');
  $('#makeInput').val('');
  $('#modelInput').val('');

  displayGarage(newCar); // NEW
}
console.log(garage);



function displayGarage(newCar) { // NEW
  console.log('in displayGarage');

  $('#garageOut ').append('<li> Year: ' + newCar.year +
    'Make: ' + newCar.make +
    'Model: ' + newCar.model + '</li>');
}
```

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <script src="scripts/jQuery.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
  <script src="scripts/client.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/style.css">

  <title>Week 6 Tier 1 Assignment</title>
</head>

<body>

  <h1><img src="images/logo.png" alt="noah's car garage"></h1>

  <h2>Please Enter your Year, Make, and Model: <span id="garageList"></span></h2>
  <input placeholder="Year" id="yearInput" />
  <input placeholder="Make" id="makeInput" />
  <input placeholder="Model" id="modelInput" />
  <button id="addCarButton">Add Car</button>


  <h3>Garage:</h3>
  <div id="garageOut"></div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

hello i cant quite figure out how to not allow a car to be added if fields are left blank, and have a maximum number of spaces in the garage which then would in turn disable inputs if the garage is full, ive posted my code that has no errors but i am working on it now. should i create a new function to check if the garage is full or can I have it in my existing newCars function?

Comment: Did the below answers help you?

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using the native HTML5 forms API. This will simplify form validation and retrieving your form.

Here's an example: https://codepen.io/sodapop/pen/jOMwZQX?editors=1111

Rather than targeting each node individually, I use the form to select all inputs and iterate through them en masse.

This scales much better if you decide to add additional fields. It also makes it easier to disable all.

```js
// Var to store car info lists
const parkingSpaces = [];

// Set your garage limit
const LIMIT = 5

/*
* @summary Function to disable all inputs
*
* @param {HTMLInputElement[]} inputs An array-like nodelist of input elements.
*/
const disableInputs = (inputs) =>
  Array.from(inputs).forEach((input) => {
    input.setAttribute("disabled", true);
  });

/*
* @summary Generates list/list nodes out of form input and pushes list to parkingSpaces.
*
* @param {HTMLInputElement[]} inputs An array-like nodelist of input elements.
*/
const addToGarage = (inputs) => {
  const ul = document.createElement("ul");
  Array.from(inputs).forEach((input) => {
    const li = document.createElement("li");
    li.innerHTML = `${input.name}: ${input.value}`;
    ul.append(li);
  });
  parkingSpaces.push(ul);
};

const handleSubmit = (e) => {
  // Prevent the page from reloading on submit
  e.preventDefault();
  const garage = document.querySelector("#garage");
  const inputs = e.target.getElementsByTagName("input");

  // Add nodes to array
  addToGarage(inputs);

  // If limit oflist items is reached, disable inputs.
  if (parkingSpaces.length >= LIMIT) {
    disableInputs(inputs);
  }

  // Append nodes array to garage div.
  garage.append(...parkingSpaces);

  // Clear form on add.
  e.target.reset();
};
```

And with your HTML, wrap your inputs in a `form` and use HMTL5 validation attributes:

```html
<form id="form" onsubmit="handleSubmit(event)">
  <input name="make" type="text" required>
  <input name="model" type="text" required>
  <input name="year" type="text" required>
  <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>

<ul id="garage"></ul>
```

You can learn about the various validation attributes here:
https://www.the-art-of-web.com/html/html5-form-validation/

Answer (score 0):

Alrighty so you have two questions -

1. How can I disable inputs if an array is full?
2. How do I not allow inputs if all fields aren't filled?

Well first you need to ask yourself how many cars you want to fit in your garage array. For an example, let's say you can only fit 10 cars. And for not allowing inputs if all fields aren't filled, you need to add an onclick function to the "addCarButton".

To not allow input unless all fields are filled add the following to your addCar function

```
if($(#yearInput).val(''); || $(#makeInput).val('')||         $(#modelInput.val(''))  {
alert("hey! Fill out all the field!");
} else {
  garage.push(newCar);
  }
```

What I am doing here is checking if any of the inputs are left blank, if they are not I am pushing the car to the array.

> How can I disable inputs if an array if full?

Add an if statement to determine whether or not the array is full
(something like if(garage.length === 10)) and then disable all inputs using the .prop Jquery property. EX: $(#yearModel).prop("disabled", true)

Comment: would i add the if statement to check and see if there is too many cars in the addCar function underneath the other if statement you wrote out?

Answer (score 0):

In this code, the fields are checked on the availability of the record through the `if` condition.

```
if (newCar.year && newCar.make && newCar.model !== '') {
    garage.push(newCar);

    $('#yearInput').val('');
    $('#makeInput').val('');
    $('#modelInput').val('');

    displayGarage(newCar);
  } else {
    console.log('All fields must be filled');
  }
```

```js
$(document).ready(readyNow);

let garage = [];

function readyNow() {
  //console.log('JQ');
  $('#addCarButton').on('click', addCar)
} //end readyNow

function addCar() {
  //console.log('in addCar');
  //get unser inputs
  //create new object
  let newCar = {
    year: $('#yearInput').val(),
    make: $('#makeInput').val(),
    model: $('#modelInput').val()
  }
  //push the new car into the array
  if (newCar.year && newCar.make && newCar.model !== '') {
    garage.push(newCar);
    //empty inputs
    $('#yearInput').val('');
    $('#makeInput').val('');
    $('#modelInput').val('');

    displayGarage(newCar); // NEW 
  } else {
    console.log('All fields must be filled');
  }
}
//console.log(garage);



function displayGarage(newCar) { // NEW
  //console.log('in displayGarage');
  
  

  $('#garageOut ').append('<li> Year: ' + newCar.year +
    'Make: ' + newCar.make +
    'Model: ' + newCar.model + '</li>');
       
    
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

  <h1><img src="images/logo.png" alt="noah's car garage"></h1>

  <h2>Please Enter your Year, Make, and Model: <span id="garageList"></span></h2>
  <input placeholder="Year" id="yearInput" />
  <input placeholder="Make" id="makeInput" />
  <input placeholder="Model" id="modelInput" />
  <button id="addCarButton">Add Car</button>


  <h3>Garage:</h3>
  <div id="garageOut"></div>
```